# How do I exchange data via Bluetooth using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, gamekit

How do I exchange data programmatically via Bluetooth using the iPhone SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To exchange data using the iPhone SDK, you should to use the [GameKit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/_index.html).

You can look at [this sample code](http://xxki.com/tutorial/pukiwiki.php?MacOS%2FiPhone%20-%20GameKit), or [this sample code from a live app](http://arctouch.com/beamit/developers/) in the app store, or the code mentioned by Randolph, [here](http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2009/03/sample-source-code-iphone-os-30-peer-to.html).

The basic process is setting up a controller and a delegate to handle the bluetooth connection for you. Your delegate needs to handle things like "Connected to peer" or "Received data".

Also, you should note that the simulator does *not* work with bluetooth and so you will need two real iOS devices or more to test with.